# ¿Por qué todas las demás imágenes se mueven cuando hago el hover en una?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy intentando crear una galería ý resulta que cada vez que intento pasar el mouse para ver el efecto hover, pues las demas imagenes como que se mueven. Afecta un poco a las demás imágenes.

Acá os dejo mi html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Galería</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="galeria">
      <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />

      <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

y este es mi css:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #000500;
}

.galeria {
  width: 100%;
}

.galeria img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #484848;
  opacity: .5;
}

.galeria img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

No se si tiene que ver con el tamaño de mi pantalla. Tengo una laptop hp, o si tiene que ver conn alguna propiedad en específico o la forma en que uso los selectores.

Comment: Hola, es simple, eso pasa por que en la clase `galeria img` tienes `border: 1px`, pero en la clase `galeria img:hover` tienes `border: 2px`, pon los 2 bordes con igual valor y se resuelve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es simple la respuesta, solo tienes que agregarle `border: 1px solid #fff;` en el hover para que no se muevan las imagenes, esto se genera automaticamente en el html básico.

Quedaría así:

**HTML**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #000500;
}

.galeria {
  width: 100%;
}

.galeria img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #484848;
  opacity: .5;
}

.galeria img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Galería</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="galeria">
      <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />

      <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me ha resuelto. Pensé que le podía cambiar el tamaño al border sin que se afectara la imagen.